# Can I replace the term “product of interest” with “interested product”?

Tags: difference

Can I replace the term “product of interest” with “interested product”? What’s the difference between the two?
What I’m trying to convey is the product that an individual is interested in.

For example:

The company wants to understand the customer’s product of interest.

The company wants to understand the customer’s interested product.

Comment: "The product the customer is interested in" is probably the most natural sounding, to my ear. Or "the customer's potential purchase".

Comment: of interest: This is an issue of interest to me. product of interest is not a usual thing.

Comment: I wouldn't use either of these TBH. The second makes no sense, and the first is not very idiomatic. Try "the customer's interest in the product".

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any example, but depending on the context, "interested product" may not be at all what you intended to say, i.e. "no," you cannot use it as a replacement for "product of interest."

You need to make sure that you understand the distinction between the use of "interested" and "interesting."  It may be that "interested" is used in a passive-voice construction, but "interesting" would be the adjectival form.  Without an example sentence, it is simply not possible to know whether in your case the substitution to which you refer could be correct.

Some examples:

- I am interested.

Meaning: I have interest (in something).

- I am interesting.

Meaning: You should be interested in me.

- The customer's product of interest was the most expensive one.

Meaning: The customer had interest in the expensive product.
(In this case, "interested product" *cannot* replace "product of interest.")

- The interested product was the most expensive one.

Meaning: The product in question (being addressed) was the expensive one.
(In this case, "product of interest" *could* replace "interested product.")

NOTE: The word "interest" can have multiple senses of meaning.  Which sense it carries is of significance to this question.

> For example:
>
> The company wants to understand the customer’s product of interest.
>
> The company wants to understand the customer’s interested product.

Of the two examples now provided in the question, only the first is correct.  The second example implies that the *product* has interest (in something)--which makes no sense (unless the "product" is living, intelligent beings).

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for such a detailed answer!